# No any bootstrap css applies to webpage when i run it in firefox,but works fine with IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to twitter bootstrap.No any bootstrap css applies to a webpage in firefox,but it works fine with IE.

I am running bootstrap version 2.3.1 and firefox 14.
Is there any problem related to version compatibility of bootstrap?

what can be a problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [Firefox's Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for errors, you might find the answer to your problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Any version above [Version 5](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Browser-Compatibility) should work.